# Python version of Arduino's Serial.available

Tags: python, embedded-linux, pyserial

I'm trying to run an infinite loop in which the extension and movement of a linear actuator is controlled. The extension amount is controlled by user input with a value from 0 to 9, i.e. if I hit 9 and enter, the actuator will extend to maximum extension and if I hit 5 and enter, the actuator will go back to 50% extension.

I'm using a PINE A64+ with an MCP3008 connected to the Pi-2 bus and simply trying to replace a setup I had, with an Arduino + actuator, with a standalone embedded Linux setup.

I'm not sure how to go about having the program monitor raw_input consistently while running an infinite loop in the background. I was able to do this in my arduino code with the following:

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  userInput = Serial.read()-48;
  Serial.println(userInput);
}
```

How would I go about doing something like this in Python? I've tried using PySerial's inWaiting command but that doesn't give me the same result. Essentially I want the program to do either one of the two possibilites:

1. Use an if statement within the loop to only assign a new value to
   the variable used if there is user input, or
2. To monitor for input constantly, and when there is an input, to break the loop, assign anew value for the variable being used by the loop, and re-enter the loop.

It would look something like this:

```
# begin loop w/ while True statement

# using if statement to enter only if there is user input, otherwise pass over
if Whatever:
    Terminal[0] = user input

getVal = analogRead(0, PI2CLK, PI2MOSI, PI2MISO, PI2CS) 

if (positionArray[Terminal[0]] - 10) < getVal < (positionArray[Terminal[0]] + 10):
    PWM0A.stop()
    PWM0B.stop()
elif getVal > positionArray[Terminal[0]]:
    PWM0A.start(100)
    PWM0B.stop()
elif getVal < positionArray[Terminal[0]]:
    PWM0A.stop()
    PWM0B.start(100)

# end loop
```

What's the best way of going about this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you please provide some more information about the hardware/software setup? How are you running Python on the arduino resp. how do you interface to the arduino?

Comment: @albert I'm using a PINE A64+ with an MCP3008 connected to the Pi-2 bus. There's no Arduino involved. I'm simply replacing the setup I had with an Arduino, with a standalone embedded Linux system.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html):

```
 in_waiting
    Getter: Get the number of bytes in the input buffer
    Type:   int

    Return the number of bytes in the receive buffer.
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - I noticed I screwed up on the logic in my head a bit. I was trying to use the same internal serial port (the one I was using the execute the python script) to input information. Obviously this won't work. This is also why my inWaiting function was giving strange results.

Essentially, I opened a new COM port using serial.Serial (ttyS0), brought up a new terminal window to send data to ttyS0, then used the serial.inWaiting command to rerun the if statement each time a new value was entered. This time it was working correctly. Basically the same thing I did in my Arduino code. Doh :)